# Accessing the containing object of a function by name in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, this

I'm wondering if somebody can comment (with citations) on whether the following is correct or will fail at some point?

```
var myObj = {  
    x: 10,
    getX: function getX() {
        return myObj.x;
    }
}
```

I believe that this is the better way to return x, however one of my colleagues prefers to bind to this.x and use that.

```
var myObj = {  
    x: 10,
    getX: function getX() {
        var thisObj = this;
        return thisObj.x;
    }
}
```

I cannot find any specific examples that support me ( maybe because I'm wrong? ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the 2nd solution is better.

Consider this:

```
var myObj = {  
  x: 10,
  getX: function getX() {
    return myObj.x;
  }
}

var anotherObj = myObj;

myObj.getX();      // return myObj.x
anotherObj.getX(); // ERROR, never return anotherObj.x
```

But if you use `this` instead, you won't have the problem.

```js
var myObj = {
    x: 10,
    getX: function() { // you may not need the function name
        return this.x;
    }
};

var anotherObj = myObj;

console.log(myObj.getX());      // return myObj.x
console.log(anotherObj.getX()); // return anotherObj.x
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,I did find a problem with this approach where passing functions as arguments binds to window as this, it was resolved by using bind or apply but something to watch out for